# How to use pywinauto to save html in internet explorer

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to use `pywinauto` to save a webpage in internet explorer.

When the program executes `type_keys('^s')`, an error appears

What should I do to save the webpage?

Thank you very much.

```
web_address = r'http://www.apple.com'
app = application.Application().start(
    r"c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe {}".format(web_address))
ie =  app.window(title_re = ".*Windows Internet Explorer.*")
ie.type_keys('^s')

raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)

pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re': '.*Windows Internet Explorer.*', 'backend': 'win32', 'process': 21052}
```

Comment: Should be `ie.type_keys("%FA")` according to this example: [save_from_internet_explorer.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/save_from_internet_explorer.py)